# breakdown xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium

I am looking at the website. Trying to transfer selenium html to junit but could not get it to work because it keeps saying Error: Element not found. Maybe syntax error because I was able to break it down to the shortest path in firebug but still could not get to compile..What do you do in this case ?

Enrollment

I use firebug Xpath to get the value of the above link
/html/body/div[@id='contentDisplayPane']/div[@id='mainDiv']/div[@id='mainDivContent']/div[@id='simpleBox']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[@id='fb_PageContent']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a

Using firebug xpath, I was able to break it down to this and able to access Enrollment link..However when I put this in the junit test case selenium.click(("//div[@id='simpleBox']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[@id='fb_PageContent']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a");
I get ERROR: Element //div[@id='simpleBox']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[@id='fb_PageContent']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a") not found

Any help or tip is appreciated

Comment: I also "love to know" what is the XML document you are issuing these XPath expressions on? Could you, please, provide it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey If you want to click any Link on your web page.
You have to first find Xpath of this Element/Text, For this you can use Firebug.So here an ex: You can use in IDE selenium.click(//a[text()="ON"]) and convert it to junit and get this 
selenium.click("//a[text()=\"HereYouCanPutYourText\"]");

please feel free if you have any concern..

Answer (score 0):

Are the tbody elements actually in the html or just being inserted by Firefox?  If Firefox is inserting the tbody and your junit tests are driving a different browser, the tbody might not be there.  Just a shot in the dark since you didn't post the document you're testing, but maybe it'll help.